# Fetched data from database not displaying in FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, react-native-flatlist

Exactly as the title says I am fetching data from a database and trying to display the stored image URI as an image in my React Native application. I'm not entirely sure where the process is going wrong, but my array is being filled and nothing is being shown. I have tried hardcoding the data that's being fetched into my application and it is being displayed then. I have wrapped my view statement that the flatlist is nested into with the following: {arrayName && .... }. Here is some relevant code. The Test field appears, but the flatlist will not.

```js
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const userImgData = [];


        {userImgData && <View style={{width: 300, height: 300}}>
          <FlatList
            data={userImgData}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            key={item=> item.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              //<Text style={styles.headerText}>{item.id}</Text>
              <Image source={{ uri: item.imageURI}} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
            )}
          />
          <Text>Test</Text>
        </View>}
```

My array is set here...

```js
  function getData(){
    axios.get('IP/imagefiles')
    .then((response) => {
      const myObjects = response.data;
      setData(myObjects);
    });
    //console.log(data);
    for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      if(data[i].user == user){
        userImgData.push(data[i]);
      }else{
        console.log('no data found!');
      };
    };
    console.log(userImgData);
  };
```

Here is how the data is coming across...
[image]

**Edit: Changed userImgData to a state variable and got some results to show.**

Comment: When you use the commented-out `<Text>{item.id}</Text>`, does that show anything?

Comment: @Phil Regarding comment #1, it did not display anything. added comment #2, data is set in state above with the setData function.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a couple of issues present...

1. You're trying to loop over `data` before it is assigned a value. This is because the Axios request is asynchronous so the code after the request runs before the code in the `then()` callback.
2. `userImgData` isn't a state variable and even if it was, using `push()` won't trigger a state update and won't re-render your component.

Try using a [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) to provide the filtered `userImgData` instead

```js
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const userImgData = useMemo(
  () => data.filter((d) => d.user == user),
  [data, user]
);

const getData = async () => {
  setData((await axios.get("IP/imagefiles")).data);
};
```

You can check `userImgData.length` to conditionally render the list.